# Hide Custom Dialog after progress bar filled 100%

Tags: android, firebase, progress-bar, android-alertdialog, firebase-storage

I tried to  display a custom dialog box with  progress bar while a file upload into firebase server. everything works fine.  but when I try to hide  dialog box after  progress bar  filled 100%  ( added dialog.dimiss()  to on success listener).   it even stopped updating progressbar

```
Dialog dialog:
          uploadTask.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                      dialog = new Dialog(mainpanel.this);
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
                    lp.copyFrom(psdialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
                    lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                    lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

                   dialog.setContentView(R.layout.progressbarlayout);
                    dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");

                    View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.progressbarlayout, null, false);
                    dialog.setContentView(dialogView);
                   status = (ProgressBar) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

status.setProgress(currentprogress);

                   dialog.show();
                   dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
                }
.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

             Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "upload succesful";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();
              dialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: Is onSuccess being called? Where/how do you declare the dialog?

Comment: .addOnSuccessListener      dialog.dismiss();

Comment: Is it being called when you run the app?

Comment: yes. when download completed it  should trigger dialog.dismiss();  but the problem is when I add this line   on succes listner    eventhough dialog box displays with progress bar. progressbar not filling. but I recive download completed toast without any problem.    If I  remove dialog.dismiss from  on succes listner. everything works fine except I cant dismiss the dialog box after progressbar filled 100%